# Overriding default value in derived class (c#)

Tags: c#, default, overriding

If i have an accessor and default property in a base class as follows:

```
class base{
protected int _foo = 5;
public int foo {get{return _foo;}set{_foo = value;}}
}
```

Then I derive this class, is it possible to override the default value of _foo?

```
class derived:base{
// foo still returns 5?
protected new int _foo = 10;
}
```

Comment: Your code formatting is a little odd: .NET code uses PascalCase for classes and class members (i.e. `Base`, `Derived`, `Foo`). You should [avoid protected fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778773/best-way-to-expose-protected-fields).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `_foo = 5` statement effectively executes in the base class's constructor. You can add code to the derived class constructor that changes `foo`'s value immediately afterwards:

```
class derived:base{
    public derived()
    {
        foo = 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a construtor to initialise the derived class and set the base types _foo property:

```
class derived:base
{
    public derived()
    {
        this._foo = 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a property:

```
protected virtual int _foo { get { return 5; } }
```

and

```
protected override int _foo { get { return 10; } }
```

Comment: it is not a constant. Calling the virtual property in the constructor (eg. to initialize the variable) is not recommended, because of side effects, CA will complain (you call derived code when base class is not initialized).

Comment: That's fine but i cant assign 'foo' anything anymore.

Comment: it's not a default value, it's more like fixed value because when you set value you will never get it back