# What C# naming scheme can be used for Property & Member that is CLS compliant?

Tags: c#, cls-compliant

Consider the following code that is not CLS Compliant (*differs only in case*):

```
protected String username;

public String Username { get { return username;} set { username = value; } }
```

So i changed it to:

```
protected String _username;

public String Username { get { return _username;} set { _username = value; } }
```

Which is also not CLS-compliant (*has leading underscore*).

Is there any common naming scheme for members/properties that doesn't violate cls compliance

Comment: Have you considered: public String Username { get; set; } ?

Comment: try like this ...public String Username { get; protected set;}

Comment: why is the field protected, not private? Your setter is already public, so there is never a need for derived classes to access the field directly.

Comment: @CodeInChaos You'd have to ask the person who originally wrote it four years ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than exposing the backing field, make your property virtual so inheritors can override the functionality without exposing the implementation of your backing field.

```
private String username;

public virtual String Username { get { return username;} set { username = value; } }
```

Inherits shouldn't have to know anything your classes implementation.

See [Best way to expose protected fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778773/best-way-to-expose-protected-fields)

Comment: So, all-in-all, there's no way to salvage the code that's there. +1 for a virtual property

Answer (score 2):

This set of rules applies to Visual Basic, but there should be a similar set for C#:

An element name in Visual Basic must observe the following rules:

> It must begin with an alphabetic character or an underscore (_).
>
> It must only contain alphabetic characters, decimal digits, and underscores.
>
> It must contain at least one alphabetic character or decimal digit if it begins with an underscore.
>
> It must not be more than 1023 characters long.

However, the following also applies:

> Element names starting with an underscore (_) are not part of the Common Language Specification (CLS), so CLS-compliant code cannot use a component that defines such names. However, an underscore in any other position in an element name is CLS-compliant.

The above was from the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81ed9a62%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Here is a link to the [Common Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3%28VS.90%29.aspx) documentation on MSDN which, in turn, references the ultimate arbiter of the CLS naming convention: [Annex 7 of Technical Report 15 of the Unicode Standard 3.0](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/tr15-18.html#Programming%20Language%20Identifiers).

Answer (score 1):

MFC to the rescue. Just use the old m_ prefix:

```
private string m_Username;
public string Username ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve with this?

```
public String Username {get; protected set};
```

or

```
private String _username;

protected void setUserName(String argUsername);
{
  if (_username != Username) // an overload of String.Compare would be better here
  {
    _username = value;
    // Do the stuff you have to do because username has changed
  }
}

public String Username {get {return _username;} protected set {setUsername(value);}}
```

Your way, to get CLS compliance you'd have to call you pulic and prtectred versions different names, which would be 'erm confusing.